# Filter Json response from Facebook

Tags: c#, json, linq, lambda, json.net

I'm trying to filter Json response using Json2Linq of Json.Net but error was occurred during filtering says "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty." 
below are my code on C#

```
   JObject rss = JObject.Parse(userJson);

        try
        {
            var FriendsLikes = from c in rss["friends"].First()["data"]
                               .SelectMany(l => l["likes"]
                               .Select(d => d["data"]).Where(r => r["id"].Value<string>() == "475729939105078")).Values<string>()
                               group c by c into g
                               orderby g.Count() descending
                               select new { FriendsLikes = g.Key };

            foreach (var item in FriendsLikes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.FriendsLikes);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Facebook Json Response

```
{
"id": "999999999084775",
"name": "Alex Xx",
"first_name": "Alex",
"last_name": "Xx",
"gender": "male",
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/101999999999999/",
"locale": "en_US",
"email": "alexxxx@gmail.com",
"picture": {
    "data": {
        "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/18341660_101370733774524_7009999999999957463_n.jpg?oh=ec8675dfe23bbda00b6048647af62875&oe=59C0F7DF",
        "is_silhouette": false
    }
},
"friends": {
    "data": [{
        "id": "10213045626997937",
        "name": "Jayson Raga",
        "first_name": "Jayson",
        "last_name": "Ragasa",
        "gender": "male",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10213045626997937/",
        "locale": "en_US",
        "picture": {
            "data": {
                "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/16114608_10211941851924250_4611916174586601978_n.jpg?oh=de4c0a7839e7e9e7ef6e29e18b885ef898&oe=59A99999",
                "is_silhouette": false
            }
        },
        "likes": {
            "data": [{
                "live_videos": {
                    "data": [{
                        "from": {
                            "name": "MyBeat",
                            "id": "475728822105078"
                        },
                        "permalink_url": "/MyBeat/videos/1283448691726531/",
                        "description": "@[141752355816253]:behind the decks live",
                        "creation_time": "2016-07-03T17:20:49+0000",
                        "id": "1261428671666530"
                    }]
                },
                "id": "475723939105078"
            }]
        }
    }]
},
```

}

My goal in my code is to filter all my friends like and return all likes from ID:475723939105078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a preliminary problem.  You are querying for `r["id"].Value<string>() == "475729939105078"` but the ID value in the JSON is actually:

```
            "id": "475723939105078"
```

These need to be the same.  I'll assume this is a typo in the question.

Your query consists of several parts -

1. You are looping through all `like` data objects inside nested arrays  `"friends.data[*].likes.data[*]"`, where `[*]` indicates an array index wildcard using [JSONPath syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).
2. You are filtering those objects with `id == "475723939105078"`
3. You seem to be grouping duplicates and ordering by count -- though I'm not sure of this since [`.Values<string>()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Values__1.htm) is intended to get the values of a primitive properties whereas the `like.data` objects are not, in fact primitives, so this part of the query fails.

Also, you are mixing LINQ and Lambda syntax, which makes things more confusing.  I'd suggest choosing one and sticking with it.

The first two parts of the query can be accomplished using LINQ syntax as follows:

```
        var id = "475723939105078";
        var friendLikesFiltered 
            = from f in rss["friends"]["data"]  // Loop through all entries f in friends.data
              from l in f["likes"]["data"]      // Then loop all entries in likes.data
              where (string)l["id"] == id       // where like.id == friendId
              select l;
```

Or using lambda:

```
        var id = "475723939105078";
        var friendLikesFiltered 
            = rss["friends"]["data"]
            .SelectMany(f => f["likes"]["data"])
            .Where(l => (string)l["id"] == id);
```

And finally using [`SelectTokens()` with JSONPath](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm):

```
        var id = "475723939105078";
        var friendLikesFiltered
            = rss.SelectTokens("friends.data[*].likes.data[*]")
            .Where(l => (string)l["id"] == id);
```

For comparison, in your query, the `"Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty."` error is caused by the fact that, when you do `rss["friends"]["data"].First().SelectMany(l => l["likes"])` the extra `First()` grabs the first array entry so the `SelectMany()` ends up looping through the *`like` property values* -- which is one level too deep in the token hierarchy.

As for grouping, your JSON doesn't show an example of duplicated `like` data, but you can always [`JTokenEqualityComparer`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenEqualityComparer.htm) to to identify and group identical JSON objects:

```
        var friendLikes =
            friendLikesFiltered
            .GroupBy(l => l, new JTokenEqualityComparer())
            .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
            .Select(g => g.Key);
```

(Here I use lambda syntax in order to use the custom [`IEqualityComparer<JToken>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx).)

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IG8P3Y) showing all three versions.